# Messy data shown in blade but not in mobile view

Tags: php, css, laravel

For some reason when I try to add in a navbar into my edit page, my view became messed up. I don't know why this is happening, I thought it might be the work of the css and all but I tried moving them but nothing happen. But when I try to use the developer tool which shows it in a mobile view, it became neat again. Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

This is the blade view:

[image]

This is the mobile view:

[image]

Here is the edit.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Summary')
@section('content')
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#ADD8E6"> 
        <link href="{{ asset('css/homeStyle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id) }}">
                        {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <label class="col-md-2"><b>Name AS PER NRIC/PASSPORT:</b></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="Name" value="{{ $object->Name }}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-md-2"><b>Alias:</b></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="Alias" value="{{ $object->Alias }}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-md-2"><b>Email:</b></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" name="Email" value="{{ $object->Email }}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-md-2"><b>Mobile Number:</b></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="number" name="Mobile_No" value="{{ $object->Mobile_No }}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-md-2"><b>Telephone Number:</b></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="number" name="Tele_no" value="{{ $object->Tele_no }}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-md-2"><b>NRIC:</b></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="NRIC" value="{{ $object->NRIC }}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
        @if(count($errors))
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{$error}}
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: use col-md-4 instead col-md-2 and col-md-8 instead col-md-6 check after that

Comment: There a big gap in between the Name, Alias, ... and the text box now @GauravGupta

Comment: Your code looks a little messed up. You extend `layouts.app` but use `html`, `head` and `body` tag inside `content` section

Comment: do one thing make div with class row for every label + input @dkna

Comment: I had used them before putting the layouts.app so I didn't really know if I should continue using it @DestinationN

Comment: @GauravGupta do you mean something like this? 
         <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-4"><b>Name AS PER NRIC/PASSPORT:</b></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input type="text" name="Name" value="{{ $object->Name }}" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: @Dkna Please stop using it. But if you take a look at the bootstrap layout documentation each row in bootstrap can have 12 columns.

Comment: @Dkna Yes something like this would be good

Comment: yes @Dkna that what i mean

Comment: Understood will try it now, give me 10 minutes and I will get back to you

Comment: @GauravGupta it didn't really change much after adding the div class="row", do you want me to update the question and show you the code that I just changed to check if I did any mistake?

Comment: yes please update code or past your code on pastbin and give it's link

Comment: I found out how to make the text box near the Name, Alias, etc already, all i have to do was to change the col-md-4 to col-md-2 instead

Comment: @GauravGupta could you post your answer below so I can mark it right and upvote it since it has helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all remove html head and body tags from it as there is already in layout then try to add div with row and make it like size of row is 12 so what you have to do is make your class like it's equal 12 give you what you desire further check [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-example-basic)

```
@extends('layouts.app')
    @section('title', 'Summary')
    @section('content')
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#ADD8E6"> 
    <link href="{{ asset('css/homeStyle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <div class="form-group">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id) }}">

              {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
              {{ csrf_field() }}


                <div class='row' >  
                  <label class="col-md-4"><b>Name AS PER NRIC/PASSPORT:</b></label>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" name="Name" value="{{ $object->Name }}" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>


                <div class='row' >  
                  <label class="col-md-4"><b>Alias:</b></label>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" name="Alias" value="{{ $object->Alias }}" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>

              <div class='row' >  
                <label class="col-md-4"><b>Email:</b></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="email" name="Email" value="{{ $object->Email }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='row' >  
                <label class="col-md-4"><b>Mobile Number:</b></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="number" name="Mobile_No" value="{{ $object->Mobile_No }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='row' >  
                <label class="col-md-4"><b>Telephone Number:</b></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="number" name="Tele_no" value="{{ $object->Tele_no }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class='row' >  
                <label class="col-md-4"><b>NRIC:</b></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" name="NRIC" value="{{ $object->NRIC }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8-offset-4">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
                </div>
              </div>

          </form>
    </div>
      @if(count($errors))
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
              {{$error}}
        </div>
         @endforeach
      @endif
    </div>
    @endsection
```

hope it will help you!

Comment: Using `form-group` instead of `row` would also work as suggested in the [relevant section of the bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal)